# Using JS To Add Text To GridView Column On Button Press

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I have a gridview that generates data from a table on a server. I have added a button at the beginning of the grid and have an empty column at the end of the grid.

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MergeInfoGrid" class="FirstCarInfoGrid" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="MergeInfoGrid_RowDataBound">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Switch">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnSwitch" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Switch" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

cs:

```
protected void bindMergeInfoGrid()
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Connection);
    sqlConn.Open();
    //vehicle 1//
    string V1Firstname = "";
    string V1LastName = "";
    string V1Address = "";
    string V1City = "";
    string V1State = "";
    string V1Zipcode = "";
    string V1Phone = "";
    string V1Cell = "";
    string V1Plate = "";
    string V1Vin = "";
    string V1ManuVin = "";
    DateTime V1PurchaseDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    string V1eMail = "";
    string V1Notes = "";
    string strQuery = "SELECT Firstname, LastName, Address, City, State, Zipcode, Phone, Cell, LicensePlate, Vin, ManuVin, Purchasedate, EMail, Notes FROM Cusdata where LicensePlate = '" + mergeCarPlate.Text.Trim() + "'";
    SqlCommand cmdQuery = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlConn);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmdQuery.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        V1Firstname = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? "" : reader.GetString(0);
        V1LastName = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? "" : reader.GetString(1);
        V1Address = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? "" : reader.GetString(2);
        V1City = reader.IsDBNull(3) ? "" : reader.GetString(3);
        V1State = reader.IsDBNull(4) ? "" : reader.GetString(4);
        V1Zipcode = reader.IsDBNull(5) ? "" : reader.GetString(5);
        V1Phone = reader.IsDBNull(6) ? "" : reader.GetString(6);
        V1Cell = reader.IsDBNull(7) ? "" : reader.GetString(7);
        V1Plate = reader.IsDBNull(8) ? "" : reader.GetString(8);
        V1Vin = reader.IsDBNull(9) ? "" : reader.GetString(9);
        V1ManuVin = reader.IsDBNull(10) ? "" : reader.GetString(10);
        V1PurchaseDate = reader.IsDBNull(11) ? DateTime.MinValue : reader.GetDateTime(11);
        V1eMail = reader.IsDBNull(12) ? "" : reader.GetString(12);
        V1Notes = reader.IsDBNull(13) ? "" : reader.GetString(13);
    }
    reader.Close();

    //vehicle 2//
    string V2Firstname = "";
    string V2LastName = "";
    string V2Address = "";
    string V2City = "";
    string V2State = "";
    string V2Zipcode = "";
    string V2Phone = "";
    string V2Cell = "";
    string V2Plate = "";
    string V2Vin = "";
    string V2ManuVin = "";
    DateTime V2PurchaseDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    string V2eMail = "";
    string V2Notes = "";
    strQuery = "SELECT Firstname, LastName, Address, City, State, Zipcode, Phone, Cell, LicensePlate, Vin, ManuVin, Purchasedate, EMail, Notes FROM Cusdata where LicensePlate = '" + mergePlateSearch.Text.Trim() + "'";
    cmdQuery = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlConn);
    reader = cmdQuery.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        V2Firstname = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? "" : reader.GetString(0);
        V2LastName = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? "" : reader.GetString(1);
        V2Address = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? "" : reader.GetString(2);
        V2City = reader.IsDBNull(3) ? "" : reader.GetString(3);
        V2State = reader.IsDBNull(4) ? "" : reader.GetString(4);
        V2Zipcode = reader.IsDBNull(5) ? "" : reader.GetString(5);
        V2Phone = reader.IsDBNull(6) ? "" : reader.GetString(6);
        V2Cell = reader.IsDBNull(7) ? "" : reader.GetString(7);
        V2Plate = reader.IsDBNull(8) ? "" : reader.GetString(8);
        V2Vin = reader.IsDBNull(9) ? "" : reader.GetString(9);
        V2ManuVin = reader.IsDBNull(10) ? "" : reader.GetString(10);
        V2PurchaseDate = reader.IsDBNull(11) ? DateTime.MinValue : reader.GetDateTime(11);
        V2eMail = reader.IsDBNull(12) ? "" : reader.GetString(12);
        V2Notes = reader.IsDBNull(13) ? "" : reader.GetString(13);
    }
    reader.Close();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Vehicle 1", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Vehicle 2", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("What Stays", typeof(string));

    for (int rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < 13; rowCounter++)
    {
        switch (rowCounter)
        {
            case 0:
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "First Name";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1Firstname;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2Firstname;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysFirstName.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 1:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "Last Name";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1LastName;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2LastName;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysLastName.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 2:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "Address";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1Address;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2Address;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysAddress.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 3:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "City";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1City;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2City;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysCity.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 4:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "Zipcode";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1Zipcode;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2Zipcode;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysZipcode.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 5:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "Phone";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1Phone;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2Phone;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysPhone.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 6:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "Cell";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1Cell;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2Cell;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysCell.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 7:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "Plate";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1Plate;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2Plate;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysPlate.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 8:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "Vin";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1Vin;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2Vin;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysVin.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 9:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "ManuVin";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1ManuVin;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2ManuVin;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysManuVin.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 10:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "Purchase Date";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1PurchaseDate;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2PurchaseDate;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysPurchaseDate.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 11:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "eMail";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1eMail;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2eMail;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStayseMail.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
            case 12:
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Category"] = "Notes";
                dr["Vehicle 1"] = V1Notes;
                dr["Vehicle 2"] = V2Notes;
                dr["What Stays"] = WhatStaysNotes.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                break;
        }
    }
    MergeInfoGrid.DataSource = dt;
    MergeInfoGrid.DataBind();
    dataDifferenceDiv.Style.Add("Display", "block");
    sqlConn.Close();
}

public void MergeInfoGrid_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ceedfc'");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=''");
    }
    
}
```

I want to use the button to switch the content in "What Stays" Column between the data in "Vehicle 1" and "Vehicle 2" column. I also want this to be done using javascript on button click so there does not need to be any postback with each click.

Answer (score 0):

do you actually  think someone going to trudge through all that code you posted? Do you really feel it necessary to take a big wooden club, and beat the posters here into a pulp and send them to the hospital in pain and suffering  to read all of that code?

It not at all clear what all that code is supposed to do, but worse your question does not seem to follow the posted code at all either, does it?

> to use the button to switch the content in "What Stays" Column between the data in "Vehicle 1" and "Vehicle 2" column.

Where? I don't see any markup or some column called Vehicle 1.

Further more, it not even close to clear why you have all those variables and code? What for?

So, you can certainly load up a data table, and then send that to say a Gridview.

So, say we have this grid view:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            width="45%" DataKeyNames="ID" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="270" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Copy hotel" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdRow" runat="server" Text="Copy hotel" 
                       CssClass="btn"  OnClick="cmdRow_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "copy of Hotel name" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtHotelC" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

So, code to load the grid can be say this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = 
                "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GHotels.DataSource = rstData;
                GHotels.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And now we have this:

[image]

So, now lets wire up the one button row click we have, and say copy the hotel name over to the last column. This will give you an idea as to how to operate on one row you click on in the GV.

So, we can have this code for the button click:

```
    protected void cmdRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow gRow = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        string sHotelName = gRow.Cells[2].Text;

        // now copy this value over to the last colum - the label

        Label tHotel = gRow.FindControl("txtHotelC") as Label;

        tHotel.Text = sHotelName;

        // addtional information we can use aboput this row click

        Debug.Print("Row index click = " + gRow.RowIndex);
        Debug.Print("ID (data keys) = " + GHotels.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString());
        Debug.Print("FirstName = " + gRow.Cells[0].Text);
        Debug.Print("Last Name = " + gRow.Cells[1].Text);
    }
```

When I say click on the 2nd row, then the grid now shows this:

[image]

And the output window shows our additional information about the row click in question:

[image]

So, above in a nutshell shows how you can get the row information. Shows how you can have some operation occur on and againast the one row.

So, from above, you should be able to build on what kind of operation you are attempting to get working for the one row.

Once you dumped that massive amount of code you posted (to save world poverty), then we can get the code working for the row click. Once done, then we can consider moving that code to run and operate client side in JavaScript.

But, we first need to get rid of the huge mountain of code you posted - you don't need it, and then we can formulate a question - one based on not attempting to abuse and beat the posters here to death with a club and the boat-load of code you posted that does not make sense, and should not be required. In other words? Try not to show such a huge hate and dislike towards the people here on stack overflow that are willing to help you out.